# Can TabGroup Windows be Locked on Android?

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, android-orientation

My app has a handful of windows. After each of those windows is created, I have code whose intent is to lock those windows in portrait mode:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({ ... });
win.orientationModes = [ Ti.UI.PORTRAIT ];
```

I still can't believe that there isn't a more universal way of doing this for Android, but that's a gripe for another day. :-) For now, this is mostly working. I'm hoping someone here can help me remove the mostly qualifier.

The app opens with a tab group containing 4 tabs. If I rotate my device as soon as the default active tab is loaded, the layout rotates as well. Oops. In fact, if I go immediately to any of those tabs and rotate my device, the layout rotates. More oops.
However -- and this is the fun part -- if I relaunch the app and jump first to a secondary window, one loaded from one of the tab windows, and rotate my phone, no display rotation. Yay! Now I jump back to any of the tab windows, the ones that were rotating before, they no longer rotate.

Wat?!

That's the pattern I think I'm seeing right now. Anyone seen this before? I'm guessing that it's a tab group thing, but I don't see any orientation accessors in the API. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried locking the activity to portrait in the manifest file? `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: I tried one version of that, but it didn't work for me. I chose the code approach for every window because I thought it would be easier to remember every time I need to add a new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom `AndroidManifest.xml` through the help of [this](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Orientation)

and add this line in Application Blog

```
<application 
    android:debuggable="false" 
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon" 
    android:label="iVite" 
    android:name="IviteApplication" >

    <activity 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity 
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity 
        android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity"/>

</application>
```

This is right way to use. Because, In Tabbar Application. We have also need to set Tabbar Activity and its orientation Setting. Like in above code In above Code.

Here, both Activity Orientation is set through AndroidManifest.xml. 
TabbarActivity and Window Activity.

Cheers....

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid the regular maintenance of a file that feels so external to the app itself, but this is the only thing that seems to work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add this to your `tiapp.xml`

```
<android >
    <manifest>
        <application>
            <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

That will lock your entire app into portrait mode

Comment: but, when we use Tabbar application this is not working... :)

Comment: Interesting..From everything I've read, that would work. Bug or just the way TabBar apps work?